# Matplotlib. Изменения цвета кривой графика реального времени

Tags: python, matplotlib, график

Есть график реального времени:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import as np
pause=3 #Пауза между отрисовками графика
plt.ion()
plt.style.use('ggplot')
ncol=256 #Количество цветов в градации
colors=plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,ncol)#Диапазон цветов
while True:
      df=pd.read_csv('/home/gluk/realtime.csv')
      df1=df.tail(500) #Берем последние значения
      east=df1['x']
      nord=df1['y']
      time=df1['date'] # Еще есть дата в формате 2019:03:31:19:14
      for i in range(ncol): #Пытаемся менять цвета
               plt.plot(east,nord, 'g-', linewight=1.5,markersize=4, color=colors[i])
               plt.pause(pause)
```

Переменная df дописывается с определенным интервалом. Переменные east и nord случайные величины. Задача сделать так, чтобы кривая графика была раскрашена диапазоном цветов (иными словами в цвета радуги). То есть, начальные значение имели бы например, гамму синего, конечные значения гамму красного. Пример кода просто красит в один цвет. Есть ли способ сделать это с помощью matplotlib? Если нет, что из модулей стоит посмотреть. Спасибо!

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html

Comment: А вот этот параметр `'g-'` разве не цвет задаёт (и тип линии)? Попробуйте убрать это `g`.

Comment: Увы,  убрать 'g-' -  не спасет. Просто изменит весь цвет линии. А я так понял, что надо что-бы каждая из линий на каждом цикле while  была "радугой".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если принципиально именно plot-график, то:

```
for i in range(ncol-1): #Пытаемся менять цвета
    plt.plot(east[i:i+2],nord[i:i+2],lw=1.5,markersize=4, c=col[i])
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Со scatter-графиком, конечно,  все можно сделать проще, без внутреннего цикла:

```
plt.scatter(east,nord, marker='.', c=col)
```

На 500 точках разница малозаметна.